# setting either controls in an item template of a gridview in C#

Tags: c#

i have a gridview in C# in which i hd kept 2 controls in an itemtemplate. now based on certain condition i hv to show only one.

please help me

Answer (score 0):

GridView.Columns[indexOfColumnToHide].Visible = false;